# Getting a 3d model from Blender to LibGDX

Tags: 3d, libgdx, blender

I have created a 3d model for my game using Blender, but I am completely lost as to how to actually get the model from Blender to my game. I have read Xoppa's tutorial on how to load models, but I'm still lost. Do I need to get rid of the camera and lights in Blender before exporting it to a .obj file? And once I do, how do I convert it to g3dj? I can't figure out how to use fbx-conv.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same "challenge". Following the link below you will find a way to export your model with and addon.

http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/02/26/Exporting-3D-model-to-LibGDX-directly-from-Blender.aspx